# Layout moves when appending, unless I use an alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I add a DOM element to my page via the script code below, the layout gets moved to the side. But if I put an alert before the append statement, the layout doesn't move.

I want the layout to remain unchanged, without having to use an alert.

Code:

```
var $parent = $(this);
var $icon = $('<i class="icon-tags tagged" title=""></i>');
var pos = $parent.offset();
var iconPos = {
  top: pos.top + 3,
  left: pos.left + $parent.innerWidth() - 19
};
$parent.append($icon);
$icon.offset(iconPos);
```

Results in:
[image]

But when I add an alert like this:

```
var $parent = $(this);
var $icon = $('<i class="icon-tags tagged" title=""></i>');
var pos = $parent.offset();
var iconPos = {
  top: pos.top + 3,
  left: pos.left + $parent.innerWidth() - 19
};
alert('anything'); // <---- The alert
$parent.append($icon);
$icon.offset(iconPos);
```

The result is this:

[image]

This last image is what I want to achieve, without the alert.

The parent size increases by 14 pixels when the icon is appended. But this shouldn't happen.
When clicking away the alert fast enough, the layout does shift. So I'm assuming the alert dialog is blocking some kind of event.

UPDATE WITH ANSWER:

```
var $parent = $(this);
var $icon = $parent.find('i.icon-tags.tagged');
var iconPos = {
  top: 3,
  right: 5,
  position: 'absolute'
};
$icon.css(iconPos);
$parent.append($icon);
```

(thanks to Jai)
Using the css function instead of the offset function in combination with putting the position to absolute and changing the values of the icon position, it works.

Comment: Are you sure the complete DOM is loaded, before your method gets called?

Comment: @Remi yes, 100% certain.

Comment: Have you tried setting the position of the icon to absolute and using @Jai's answer?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer:**

I can understand that your parent element should be positioned relative and the icon you are trying to append should be positioned absolutely:

```
var $parent = $(this);
var $icon = $('<i class="icon-tags tagged" title=""></i>');
var pos = $parent.offset();
var iconPos = {
  position:'absolute',
  top: pos.top + 3,
  left: pos.left + $parent.innerWidth() - 19
};
$icon.css(iconPos);  // <------should be here
$parent.css('position', 'relative').append($icon); // <----then append
```

Comment: This does not work. In fact, the icon isn't even visible anymore after that because it is the parent that increases in width. Not the icon. Offsetting before adding moves the entire div even more to the side.

Comment: so why don't you set the parent style position to relative and the icon as per absolute and then set the offsets.

Comment: It works after changing the top from pos.top + 3 to just 3 and changing the left to right: 0. The parent css does not need to change this way. At least in firefox :)